# .Net webservice with name clash

Tags: .net, web-services, web-applications

I'm having trouble referencing a .Net web service within a web application. The problem arises because the webservice has another reference to an external dll with a class name identical to one of the classes within the webservice itself. Once I add that web service into my web application project, I get compilation errors from the generated class. It works fine within a website project (at least it compiles). However, if I understand correctly, a website project, unlike a web application project, compiles the code at run time. Would the webservice work in that kind of a project? And more importantly, how can I include external dlls in my webservice if they both share a class name that's identical?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say _"get **compilation errors** from the generated class. It **works fine** within a website project"_ Does it work or NOT? And what is the exact compilation error you get?

Answer (score 0):

What you would do is when you add a service reference in Visual Studio, on the bottom of the *Add Service Reference* window, the *Namespace* field. Enter a different namespace here.

In a case where you have *Ambiguous Types* error, you specify the fully qualified name of the class you want.

Example : Add your service reference with the name *"MyService"*

```
Display(MyService.Product);

Display(MyProjectNamespace.Product);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that both classes are in the same web service so adding a name space to the web service doesn't actually help since they both end up there.

Comment: @leon Ok. How can that be really? Post more details on your question (you can edit it) What type of service is this? WCF? Asmx? How can you have two same types exposed by a web service?

Comment: It's an ASMX. The webservice references a dll that has class A. If the webservice defines class A as well under a different namespace wouldn't that cause the collision?

Comment: @Leon yes possibly, but wherever visual studio gives you an _ambiguous type_ error, right click it and there will be an option to change it to the fully qualified name, with the whole namespace. This is the only way I see you can get it working..